# variable in a variable raspberry pi

Tags: php, raspberry-pi2

I was wondering if variable in a variable (I think it's called dynamic variable ) works in php while working on raspberry pi (raspbian OS), for example:

```
$a=${'slota'.$x1} * (${'slot'.$x3});
```

and if no, which is the best alternative?

Comment: No reason why that wouldn't work. Appears to be valid php. Have you tried running it? I mean as long as those variables are set it would work.

Comment: PHP running on a raspberry pi is virtually no different than any other host.  Did you try this?  Are you having any issues with it?  What makes you think it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $var1 = 'slota'.$x1;
 $var2 = 'slot'.$x3;

 $a = ($$var1 * $$var2);  /// these variables must already exists Im assuming
```